# Menu not toggling(closing) on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, navigation

I have a menu which has to be toggled (open and closed). Also if one dropdown is open, and the user clicks on some other dropdown then, in this case, the opened one has to close. In the code which I have written, I am able to achieve the scenario of closing the dropdown if the user clicks on the next. But the dropdown does not toggle when clicked on the link. It only opens. But it has to also close when the same link is clicked.

Js code.

```
$('.header-nav-menu .header-menu a.menu-item').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.header-nav-menu .header-menu ').removeClass('show-menu-dropdown');
    if ($(this).closest('.header-menu').hasClass('show-menu-dropdown')) {
        $(this).closest('.header-menu').removeClass('show-menu-dropdown');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.header-menu').addClass('show-menu-dropdown');
    }
});
```

HTML code

```
<div class="header-menu third-level">
    <a href="/en/who-we-are" class="menu-item ">Who We Are </a>
    <li class="no-submenu">
        <div class="menu-item">
            <a href="" class="sub-category active">Our Brand</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Try removing this line: `$('.header-nav-menu .header-menu ').removeClass('show-menu-dropdown');`

Comment: Can you provide full code with CSS too?

Comment: @alanfcm If I remove that,then the scenario of the dropdown closing when another is clicked fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a boolean variable to save whether or not the class is present before removing it from all the menus.  Something like this:

```
$('.header-nav-menu .header-menu a.menu-item').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var hasClass = $(this).closest('.header-menu').hasClass('show-menu-dropdown');
        $('.header-nav-menu .header-menu ').removeClass('show-menu-dropdown');

    if (hasClass){
         $(this).closest('.header-menu').removeClass('show-menu-dropdown')

    }else{
        $(this).closest('.header-menu').addClass('show-menu-dropdown')


    }

})
```